# Need help finding path to new HDD and changing location of time machine backup?

Tags: 14.04

Hello long story short I just bought a new HDD and need help changing the location of my time machine backup on my ubuntu 14.04 server.

You can edit the location of the backup by doing step 2 in this guide
http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-10-10-setting-up-mac-os-time-machine-server

This is my first time using ubuntu/linux and I have no idea what the path to my new HDD can somebody please help me by telling me what to input into the AppleVolumes.default file?

Step 2: Configure where to save the Time Machine backups. Here create a target location (`/backup/TimeMachine` for example).

Edit `/etc/netatak/AppleVolumes.default` with:

sudo gedit `/etc/netatak/AppleVolumes.default`
type in following:

```
#~/ “Home Directory”
/backup/TimeMachine “TimeMachine” options:tm
```

Here backups will be stored in `/backup/TimeMachine.`

**Control+L**: `/media/server/serverhdd`

**AppleVolumes.default file**

```
volume format:
:DEFAULT: [all of the default options except volume name]
path [name] [casefold:x] [options:z,l,j] \
[allow:a,@b,c,d] [deny:a,@b,c,d] [dbpath:path] [password:p] \
[rwlist:a,@b,c,d] [rolist:a,@b,c,d] [limitsize:value in bytes] \
[preexec:cmd] [root_preexec:cmd] [postexec:cmd] [root_postexec:cmd] \
[allowed_hosts:IPv4 address[/IPv4 netmask bits]] \
[denied_hosts:IPv4 address[/IPv4 netmask bits]] \

... more, see below ...

name: volume name. it can't include the ':' character
#
#
variable substitutions:
you can use variables for both and now. here are the

rules:
1) if you specify an unknown variable, it will not get converted.
2) if you specify a known variable, but that variable doesn't have a value, it will get ignored.
#

the variables:
$b -> basename of path
$c -> client's ip or appletalk address
$d -> volume pathname on server
$f -> full name (whatever's in the gecos field)
$g -> group
$h -> hostname
$i -> client ip without tcp port or appletalk network
$s -> server name (can be the hostname)
$u -> username (if guest, it's whatever user guest is running as)
$v -> volume name (either ADEID_NAME or basename of path)
$z -> zone (may not exist)
$$ -> $
#
#
casefold options [syntax: casefold:option]:
tolower -> lowercases names in both directions
toupper -> uppercases names in both directions
xlatelower -> client sees lowercase, server sees uppercase
xlateupper -> client sees uppercase, server sees lowercase
#
allow/deny/rwlist/rolist format [syntax: allow:user1,@group]:
user1,@group,user2 -> allows/denies access from listed users/groups
rwlist/rolist control whether or not the
volume is ro for those users.
allowed_hosts -> Only listed hosts and networks are allowed,
all others are rejected. Example:
allowed_hosts:10.1.0.0/16,10.2.1.100
denied_hosts -> Listed hosts and nets are rejected,
all others are allowed. Example:
denied_hosts: 192.168.100/24,10.1.1.1
preexec -> command to be run when the volume is mounted,
ignore for user defined volumes
root_preexec -> command to be run as root when the volume is mounted,
ignore for user defined volumes
postexec -> command to be run when the volume is closed,
ignore for user defined volumes
root_postexec -> command to be run as root when the volume is closed,
ignore for user defined volumes
veto -> hide files and directories,where the path matches
one of the "/" delimited vetoed names. Matches are
partial, e.g. path is /abc/def/file and veto:/abc/

will hide the file.
adouble -> specify the format of the metadata files.
default is "v2". netatalk 1.x used "v1".
"osx" cannot be treated normally any longer.
volsizelimit -> size in MiB. Useful for TimeMachine: limits the
reported volume size, thus preventing TM from using
the whole real disk space for backup.

Example: "volsizelimit:1000" would limit the

reported disk space to 1 GB.
#
codepage options [syntax: options:charsetname]
volcharset -> specifies the charset to be used
as the volume codepage
e.g. "UTF8", "UTF8-MAC", "ISO-8859-15"
maccharset -> specifies the charset to be used
as the legacy client (<=Mac OS 9) codepage
e.g. "MAC_ROMAN", "MAC_CYRILLIC"
#
perm -> default permission value
OR with the client requested perm
Use with options:upriv
dperm -> default permission value for directories
OR with the client requested perm
Use with options:upriv
fperm -> default permission value for files
OR with the client requested perm
Use with options:upriv
umask -> set perm mask
Use with options:upriv
dbpath:path -> store the database stuff in the following path.
cnidserver:server[:port]
-> Query this servername or IP address
(default:localhost) and port (default: 4700)
for CNIDs. Only used with CNID backend "dbd".
This option here overrides any setting from
afpd.conf:cnidserver.
password:password -> set a volume password (8 characters max)
cnidscheme:scheme -> set the cnid scheme for the volume,
default is [dbd]
available schemes: [dbd last tdb]
ea -> none|auto|sys|ad
Specify how Extended Attributes are stores. default
is auto.
auto: try "sys" (by setting an EA on the shared
directory itself), fallback to "ad". Requires
writable volume for performing the test.
Note: options:ro overwrites "auto" with "none."
sys: Use filesystem EAs
ad: Use files in AppleDouble directories
none: No EA support
#
#
miscellaneous options [syntax: options:option1,option2]:
tm -> enable TimeMachine support
prodos -> make compatible with appleII clients.
crlf -> enable crlf translation for TEXT files.
noadouble -> don't create .AppleDouble unless a resource
fork needs to be created.
ro -> mount the volume as read-only.
mswindows -> enforce filename restrictions imposed by MS
Windows. this will also invoke a default
codepage (iso8859-1) if one isn't already
specified.
nohex -> don't do :hex translations for anything
except dot files. specify usedots as well if
you want that turned off. note: this option
makes the / character illegal.
usedots -> don't do :hex translation for dot files. note: when
this option gets set, certain file names
become illegal. these are .Parent and
anything that starts with .Apple.
invisibledots -> don't do :hex translation for dot files. note: when
this option gets set, certain file names
become illegal. these are .Parent and
anything that starts with .Apple. also, dot
files created on the unix side are marked invisible.
limitsize -> limit disk size reporting to 2GB. this is
here for older macintoshes using newer
appleshare clients. yucko.
nofileid -> don't advertise createfileid, resolveid, deleteid
calls
root_preexec_close -> a non-zero return code from root_preexec close the
volume being mounted.
preexec_close -> a non-zero return code from preexec close the
volume being mounted.
nostat -> don't stat volume path when enumerating volumes list
upriv -> use unix privilege.
illegalseq -> encode illegal sequence in filename asis,
ex "\217-", which is not a valid SHIFT-JIS char,
is encoded as U\217 -
nocnidcache -> Don't store and read CNID to/from AppleDouble file.
This should not be used as it also prevents a CNID
database rebuild with dbd!
caseinsensitive -> The underlying FS is case insensitive (only
test with JFS in OS2 mode)
dropbox -> Allows a volume to be declared as being a "dropbox."
Note that netatalk must be compiled with dropkludge
support for this to function. Warning: This option
is deprecated and might not work as expected.
dropkludge -> same as "dropbox"
nodev -> always use 0 for device number, helps when the
device number is not constant across a reboot,
cluster, ...

#
The line below sets some DEFAULT, starting with Netatalk 2.1.
:DEFAULT: options:upriv,usedots
By default all users have access to their home directories.

~/ "Home Directory"
/media/server/TimeMachine TimeMachine allow:TimeMachine cnidscheme.dbd options:usedots,upriv,tm

End of File
```

Comment: you are starting with step 2?? :)

Comment: I already have the server installed problem is its installed on the same disk I have ubuntu os installed and the disk is full. I bought a new hard drive that I want my time machine backups to back up too. Step 2 tells you how to change the location the back ups are installed I just need to know how to find the path to my new hard drive and also what to change in the AppleVolumes.default file...For example it says "Home Directory" I need to know what to change that too...The /backup/TimeMachine is currently where its backing up too I need to put the path to my new HDD here. @KasiyA

Comment: Ok. plug your external HDD and then open it, next press <Ctrl>+<L> and copy that in your question and also run this command in terminal `sudo gedit /etc/netatak/AppleVolumes.default` and post content of this file in body of your question.

Comment: Okay just did it. When I did ctrl+l it just highlighted the location of the drive is that right? The whole applevolumes file was added to the question @KasiyA

Comment: Ok just replace two last line exactly with this code `#~/ "Home Directory"
/media/server/serverhdd "TimeMachine" allow:TimeMachine cnidscheme.dbd options:usedots,upriv,tm` and save this file. next follow steps

Comment: Okay I will do that thank you..The last part of your comment got cut off after "next follow steps -" @KasiyA

Comment: I means follow next steps in http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-10-10-setting-up-mac-os-time-machine-server